# Downloading binary file throws org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed

Tags: java, jersey

I'm using Jersey Multipart for uploading file to the server via Rest API. I use the InputStream object provided to me by Jersey as a parameter `@FormDataParam("upload_scn")` (`upload_scn` is defined in my index.html like this
`<div><input type="file" id="upload-suite-file" name="upload_scn" class="file_upload" ></div>`).

Just to be precise I am downloading a *.pdf file (I don't know why this is a problem because downloading small '.txt' file is fine - it always succeeds ). 
When I execute the code below :

```
private void saveToDisk(InputStream uploadedInputStream, FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
    FormDataMultiPart multiPart) {

  String uploadedFileLocation = "C:\\temp\\" + fileDetail.getFileName();
  Object str = multiPart.getField("upload_scn");
  Map<String, String> params = fileDetail.getParameters();
  System.out.println(params);
  try {

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));

    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));

    while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
      out.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }

    out.flush();
    out.close();

  } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Problem");
  }
}
```

... I am getting an exception:

```
{name=upload_scn, filename=11092019105903-0001.pdf}  
    org.jvnet.mimepull.MIMEParsingException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.WeakDataFile.read(WeakDataFile.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.DataFile.read(DataFile.java:47)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.FileData.read(FileData.java:39)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.DataHead$ReadMultiStream.fetch(DataHead.java:235)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.DataHead$ReadMultiStream.read(DataHead.java:189)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
        at com.jci.remoteUploaderResources.DownloadFile.saveToDisk(DownloadFile.java:61)
        at com.jci.remoteUploaderResources.DownloadFile.uploadFile(DownloadFile.java:42)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1839)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek0(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(RandomAccessFile.java:557)
        at org.jvnet.mimepull.WeakDataFile.read(WeakDataFile.java:82)
        ... 55 more
```

What am I doing wrong? Why the `OutputStream` `out` created from the path `uploadedFileLocation` is all of it sudden closed - I am still processing it !!!
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

If you analyse your source with [SpotBugs](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs) you get [OS_OPEN_STREAM](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bugDescriptions.html#os-method-may-fail-to-close-stream-os-open-stream) and [OS_OPEN_STREAM_EXCEPTION_PATH](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bugDescriptions.html#os-method-may-fail-to-close-stream-on-exception-os-open-stream-exception-path) warnings indicating that you may fail to close the stream:

```
com.lloyds.mavenproject1.NewClass.saveToDisk(InputStream, FormDataContentDisposition, FormDataMultiPart) may fail to close stream [com.lloyds.mavenproject1.NewClass] At NewClass.java:[line 22] OS_OPEN_STREAM
com.lloyds.mavenproject1.NewClass.saveToDisk(InputStream, FormDataContentDisposition, FormDataMultiPart) may fail to close stream on exception [com.lloyds.mavenproject1.NewClass] At NewClass.java:[line 26] OS_OPEN_STREAM_EXCEPTION_PATH
```

There is a simple way to copy all bytes from an input stream to a file - [Files.copy(in, path)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)):

```java
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\temp\\" + fileDetail.getFileName());
try (InputStream in = uploadedInputStream) {
  Files.copy(in, path);
}
```

Comment: Tried your solution but it still throws the same exception.

Comment: I have also installed SpotBugs plugin (ver. 3.1.5.r201806132012-cbbf0a5) and run it against the code above, but SpotBugs did not find any bugs.

Comment: Which version of Jersey are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.29.1. My POM looks like this:

Comment: Sorry my POM is too big to include in the comment- it gets rejected if I try to insert it.

Comment: So it's the latest version of Jersey. And the file you're trying to upload is not too big, is it? Strange. Need to investigate further, but now I don't think the issue is with the `saveToDisk` method, but, probably, with the Jersey config or the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the culprit but still don’t know why that is a problem.
My API method to upload the file was:

```
@POST
    @Path("/download")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public String uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("upload_scn") InputStream uploadedInputStream, // see index.html form for the name 'upload_scn'
            @FormDataParam("upload_scn") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData,
            @FormDataParam("upload_scn") File file

            ) {…}
```

The problem was : `@FormDataParam("upload_scn") File file`.
If I remove it from the method signature it all starts working fine.
The question is still why? Is this a jersey bug or a documented feature?

Comment: I am getting the same error with InputStream only